# How to Mock a Socket object from Socket.io

Tags: typescript, testing, socket.io, mocking, nestjs

I want to create a test for my Gateway in Nestjs. I tried to search for some mocking libraries for socket.io and no one works with TypeScript. Here is my test

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing'
import { RoomGateway } from './room.gateway'
import { Socket } from 'socket.io'

describe('RoomGateway', () => {
  let roomGateway: RoomGateway
  let socket: Socket

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const RoomModule: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [RoomGateway],
    }).compile()

    roomGateway = RoomModule.get<RoomGateway>(RoomGateway)
    socket = new Socket(null, null, null)
  })

  it('Should be defined', () => {
    expect(roomGateway).toBeDefined()
  })

  it('Should return message that wass provided', async () => {
    expect(roomGateway.handleMessage(socket, 'Hello World')).toEqual({
      event: 'message',
      data: 'Hello World',
    })
  })
})
```

Anyone knows how I can mock a Socket object in TypeScript?

Comment: Can you share a code snippet from your Gateway class?

Comment: https://github.com/Rigtch/rigtch-api/blob/master/src/room/room.gateway.ts